# "cannot open output file filename.exe: Permission denied"

Tags: c++, makefile, dev-c++

I have just learned C++ and I am trying to make a program using the windows.h header.  I am using the Dev-C++ compiler and i am getting three errors that I can't find a solution to.

These are the errors:

> cannot open output file filename.exe: Permission denied
>   [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
>   recipe for target 'filename.exe' failed

Here is my code:

```
#include &#60windows.h&$62
#include &#60iostream&#62
#include &#60fstream&#62
#include &#60string&#62
#include &#60vector&#62
using namespace std;

HWND textfield;
/* This is where all the input to the window goes to */
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
switch(Message) {
    case WM_CREATE:

            CreateWindow("STATIC",
            "DocJoin Document Combiner",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
            20,20,300,25,
            hwnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
            break;

    /* Upon destruction, tell the main thread to stop */
    case WM_DESTROY: {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }

    /* All other messages (a lot of them) are processed using default procedures */
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}

/* The 'main' function of Win32 GUI programs: this is where execution starts */
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int     nCmdShow) {
WNDCLASSEX wc; /* A properties struct of our window */
HWND hwnd; /* A 'HANDLE', hence the H, or a pointer to our window */
MSG Msg; /* A temporary location for all messages */

/* zero out the struct and set the stuff we want to modify */
memset(&wc,0,sizeof(wc));
wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc; /* This is where we will send messages to */
wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

/* White, COLOR_WINDOW is just a #define for a system color, try Ctrl+Clicking it */
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";
wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); /* Load a standard icon */
wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); /* use the name "A" to use the project icon */

if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!","Error!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,"WindowClass","DocJoin",WS_VISIBLE|WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, /* x */
    CW_USEDEFAULT, /* y */
    683, /* width */
    730, /* height */
    NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);

if(hwnd == NULL) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!","Error!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

/*
    This is the heart of our program where all input is processed and 
    sent to WndProc. Note that GetMessage blocks code flow until it receives something, so
    this loop will not produce unreasonably high CPU usage
*/
while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) { /* If no error is received... */
    TranslateMessage(&Msg); /* Translate key codes to chars if present */
    DispatchMessage(&Msg); /* Send it to WndProc */
}
return Msg.wParam;
```

}

and here is the Makefile.win:

`# Project: ProjectName`

`# Makefile created by Dev-C++ 5.6.3`

```
CPP      = g++.exe
CC       = gcc.exe
WINDRES  = windres.exe
OBJ      = main.o
LINKOBJ  = main.o
LIBS     = -L"[...]" -L"[...]" -static-libgcc -mwindows -g3
INCS     = -I"[...]" -I"[...]" -I"[...]"
CXXINCS  = -I"[..]" -I"[...]" -I"[...]" -I"[...]"
BIN      = filename.exe
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) -g3
CFLAGS   = $(INCS) -g3
RM       = rm.exe -f

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before $(BIN) all-after

clean: clean-custom
${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
$(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)

main.o: main.cpp
$(CPP) -c main.cpp -o main.o $(CXXFLAGS)
```

I spent 3 hours doing research and troubleshooting and I am just stumped.
This is my first time using a C++ compiler, meaning that its my first program.

Comment: `Permission denied` <- My guess is your exe file is still running.

Comment: I've looked through a lot of threads that say check to see if its running.  I've looked through the task manager several times and its not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875403/cannot-open-output-file-permission-denied?rq=1

Comment: The only two meaningful choices are 1) the file is locked (it may be running *or* another process may have it open for exclusive access) or; 2) the file cannot otherwise be written as the directory/device permissions does not allow it (make sure the code is being compiled from the correct *relative* directory) -- Process Explorer to search for open filehandles (sometimes an unexpected process might be the culprit).

Comment: I installed the Process Explorer and it found no process or handle related to `filename.exe`.  What is a relative directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to change the file location.

**NOTE**: Do not save your file in `Program Files` & `Program Files (x86)` in Microsoft Windows.

You can use another path for example `C:\USER\.....`

Answer (score 2):

The linker cannot delete the existing file `filename.exe` .

1. Check that "filename" process is not currently runnning.
2. Check the permissions on it
3. Try to manually delete/rename it

As far as the compiler is concerned, there is no error in the source code.

If I may, you should start with simpler applications if this is your first program (particularly, avoid GUI and go for Console applications)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue for a couple months. I tried all the solutions listed, to no avail. Today I found a solution that worked for me, and I want to share.

1 - Uninstall Dev-C++.

2 - Run regedit, find "orwell", "devcpp", "dev-++", "bloodshed", deleting every record.

3 - Run Wise Registry Cleaner, scan, cleanup, defrag registry (this step may be overkilling)

4 - Delete the program folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp" or whatever.

5 - Download the last version of Dev-C++ from Orwell.

6 - Install normally, default options all the time.

That did the trick. I'm happy.

Answer (score -2):

Save the file in any other folder as the following

C:\Users\dhanya\Documents

Comment: This is exactly the same solution as the accepted answer.