# principal = 10000, interest rate = 5% , 10000 → 20000 when will it double?

Tags: principal

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x=5;  //x = interest rate(5%)
    int y=10000; //y = principal

    int n = 0;   //n = after years
    while (1)
    {
        n++;
        y += y*(x/100);
        if(y == 20000)
            break;

    }

    printf("%d years later, double.",n);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, nothing happens.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
cannot open output file mm.exe: Permission denied   mm          C/C++ Problem

I would appreciate it if you let me know what went wrong.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Where is it getting stuck?

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
cannot open output file mm.exe: Permission denied money    C/C++ Problem

Comment: I'm not sure what that has to do with anything, but looking over your code, `y == 20000` is unlikely to be true. Try changing it to `y >= 20000`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have X as an integer and it's value is 5, at

```
y+= y*(x/100)
```

Is equivalent to

```
y+= 0
```

as (5/100) with integer division yields 0. This results in while(1) looping infinitely, and thus will never allow the program to terminate.

Additionally, the permission denied error looks like it can be fixed by changing your save file location. [Here is my source and some extra info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945456/cannot-open-output-file-filename-exe-permission-denied)

Hope this helps!