# Eclipse CDT error woes: "Type cannot open output file snackerfork.exe: Permission denied "

Tags: c, eclipse, error-handling

Just starting out. Program -if you can't tell from the error message- is thoughtfully named "snackerfork" and I get this error message a lot after building and running my source file a few times.

I know it's been asked before, but the answers all seem to revolve around either 'be less rough and wait a few minutes before rerunning your new source code', or 'get a new ide', 'restart eclipse whenever that happens', 'close the program you ran in the task manager'(for Windows(which btw, doesn't even work, since eclipse is still using the task)). The point is that I really want to use eclipse, but I need to know if there's a way to make it more like code::blocks(for example), where you can just brutally abuse your 'built and run' commands to your hearts content with nary a worry in the world.

Sorry if the question was badly formulated. This is literally my first post(constructive input on that's appreciated!)

Edit: This is a duplicate question, but here Ill try to list the proposed solutions to the original question, which explains why im reasking it(not that it's justified, but I doubt id have a better shot at finding out some other way)

-"terminate the program by pressing a key and not by clicking the close button": No, this doesn't work. The console in exclipse is built-in and isn't the sort of prompt that allows that

-"restart eclipse": 
This does work, but this error happens so fast and so often, it's just not practical

-"use a different IDE": 
Also works, but isn't exactly a solution I'm looking for

-"i got rid of it by clicking the "Terminate" button at the very top-right side 
of the console window (red button) and after that "remove all terminated launches": 
Didn't work. flat out. Terminate button isn't lit up.

-"To eliminate this problem, run the devcpp.exe as an administrator.": 
using eclipse, but still running as admin already anywho

-"Check your ANTIVIRUS Software": 
not using one

-"check that "filename.exe" is not running, I guess you are using Microsoft Windows, in that case you can use either Task Manager or Process Explorer":
Too inconvenient, and it didn't even work, as eclipse is still using the program I need to close, leading back to "restart eclipse"

Comment: Congratulations, you are successful in confusing me. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot open output file, permission denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875403/cannot-open-output-file-permission-denied)

Comment: Would a picture help? @Coolguy, YES. exact duplicate. Ive gone through at least 3 of them, but the solutions are all really bad. This happens like 30 seconds in to starting eclipse, and their solutions are essentially 'restart eclipse'

Comment: Not that it really matters anymore, but I got around it by setting eclipse to use an external console to display its console output junk. This way there arent any issues closing the program youre running