# Mingw error 2 codelite

Tags: c++, mingw, codelite

When compiling my c++ code in the Codelite IDE, I got this build output:

```
32\cmd.exe /C C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j4 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  

Makefile
"----------Building project:[ source - Debug ]----------"
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/sprv6/Desktop/codelite workspaces/Competitive neural networks/source'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/g++.exe -o ./Debug/source ./Debug/main.cpp.o   -L.
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file ./Debug/source.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/source] Error 1
source.mk:78: recipe for target 'Debug/source' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/sprv6/Desktop/codelite workspaces/Competitive neural networks/source'
mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
====1 errors, 0 warnings====
```

I have tried deselecting the option "pass object list to the linker via file", but that was unsuccessful. I also tried re-installing my compilers, with no success. I am not sure what else to do. All I know about the source of the problem is it started occurring after I mistakenly wrote some code that was trying to get values off the end of a list.

Note: I understand questions similar to this have been asked, but their solutions are not working for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot open output file, permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875403/cannot-open-output-file-permission-denied)

Comment: The error is clear, you don't have write access to `./Debug/source.exe` - it's likely still running (probably crashed horribly)

Comment: Your antivirus could also cause this.

Comment: ***after I mistakenly wrote some code that was trying to get values off the end of a list*** That likely has nothing to do with the problem other than the possibility that your program is still running from the previous attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is facing this issue (despite all of these years) and stumbles upon this post, simply run CodeLite with Admin privileges and the issue will be gone.